# Determine the diameter length (mm) of each circle shown using the given information. Geometry, trig and algebra only.

Tags: geometry

[image: Internally tangent circles puzzle]

I have considered ratios of triangles as well constructing tangent and secants to compare sides of triangles. Neither has worked out for me. Also have considered moving small circle to center but that has not been advantageous.

Comment: I love that you are allowed to combine all the methods you want, your teacher is awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call $R$ and $r$ the radius of the big and small circles repectively. Since $2r+90=2R$ we get $R=r+45$

Now notice $DB=DG=r=R-45$. Also notice $DG=\sqrt{GC^2+DC^2}$.

notice $GC=R-50$ and $DC=R-r=45$ so we get $GC^2+DC^2=R^2-100R+2500+45^2$.

So $\sqrt{R^2-100R+2500+2025}=DG=DB=R-45\implies$

$ R^2-100R+2500+2025=R^2-90R+2025$.

Notice the last part is a quadratic in $R$, so from here we can obtain $R$ which happens to be $250$.

And from here $r=R-45=205$

Comment: I was headed there but missed the DC = 45 (blindness); shouldn't 250 be 2500?

Comment: In what part of the answer?

Comment: R^2 - 100R + 250? +45^2

Comment: Yeah, I thing I fixed that half an hour ago, mabye you didn't refresh the page?

Comment: that would do the trick

Comment: Does it look ok now? The answer should be $R=250$ and $r=205$.

Answer (score 1):

If the big circle's radius is $\;R\;$ and the small circle's is $\;r\;$ , and if $\;D=(0,Y_D)\;$ , then you can check that $\;Y_D=r-R<0\;$

Since the point $\;E:=(0, Y_E)\;$ is common to both circles, then

$$\begin{cases}&Y_E^2=R^2\\{}\\&(Y_E-Y_D)^2=r^2\end{cases}$$

and since clearly $\;Y_D\,,\,\,Y_E<0\;,\;\;R,r>0\;,\;\;R>|Y_D|$ ,  we get

$$Y_E=-R\;,\;\;(-R-YD)^2=(R+Y_D)^2=r^2$$

Now,

$$90=Y_A-Y_B=R-(Y_D+r)=R-r-Y_D=-2Y_D\implies Y_D=-45$$

Try now to take it from here.

Comment: Why would you calculate $Y_D$ in such a complicated manner? If the difference in diameter is $90\text{mm}$, then clearly the difference in radius is $45\text{mm}$.

Comment: @dtldarek Do you think I plan all this? These are just several ideas for the OP for him to complete with his own effort. I do the maths while writing. As you can see from the other answer, some prefer to give up the whole work ready. I don't.

Comment: The first one was what I had been doing but missed a wee part. I greatly appreciate this second outlook for me to add to bag of tricks...

Answer (score 0):

Consider a circle around $C$, through $H$ which should be between $F$ and $G$, so that $DE = CH$ -- a circle the same size as the small one, centered at the center of the big one.  This gives $FH = 45mm$ (because the difference in radiuses is clearly $45mm$), so $GH = 5mm$.  This gives us something we can use: $GC = r-5$, $CD = 45$, and $GD = r$, and those form a right triangle.  A quick run through the pythagorean theorem and some solving finishes the job.